# Change key of an array PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array  `$theme_name`

```
Array
(
    [0] => template0
    [1] => template1
    [2] => template2
    [3] => template3
    [4] => template4
    [5] => template5
    [6] => template6
)
```

and this other array that has the same lenght `$theme_info`

```
Array
(
    [0] => my template n 00
    [1] => my template n 01
    [2] => my template n 02
    [3] => my template n 03
    [4] => my template n 04
    [5] => my template n 05
    [6] => my template n 06
)
```

Basically what I want is to have this array :

```
Array
(
    [template0] => my template n 00
    [template1] => my template n 01
    [template2] => my template n 02
    [template3] => my template n 03
    [template4] => my template n 04
    [template5] => my template n 05
    [template6] => my template n 06
)
```

Why this won't work ?

```
foreach ($themes_info as $key => $value) {
    include($value['directory']) ;
    $theme_info[] = $info;
    $theme_name[] = $value['name'];
}


 foreach ($theme_name as $key => $value) {
    $value = $theme_info[$key];
}
```

FYI `$themes_info` have all the themes with names and directories emplacement.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`array_combine()`](http://php.net/array_combine):

```
$result = array_combine($theme_name, $theme_info);
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/138154)

Comment: Thanks that's very simple!

Comment: @user3350731: Indeed. PHP has an [exhaustive list of functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/funcref.php). You should consult it before trying to implement it manually ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this far easier in PHP. Just like this:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($themes_info); $i++) {
   include($value['directory']);
   $theme_info[] = $info;
   $theme_name["someKey$i"] = $value['name'];
}
```

And replace someKey with your prefered key for that array. Or for any other array for that matter.